# Show $\text{det}(A)$ is divisible by $a^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $a \in \mathbb{Z}, a\ge2$ and $A_{n \times n}$ be a $n$ by $n$ matrix with all entries equal to $\pm a$ or $0$. I want to show $\text{det}(A)$ is divisible by $a^n$. I am aware of the basic properties of matrices, however, can't quite put my finger on how to approach this in an elegant way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the [Leibniz formula for determinants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_determinants)

$$\det(A)=\sum\limits_{\sigma\in S_n}\text{sgn}(\sigma)\prod\limits_{i=1}^na_{\sigma(i),i}$$

Since for every pattern $\sigma$ one has $\prod\limits_{i=1}^n a_{\sigma(i),i}$ will equal either $\pm a^n$ (*in the case none of the terms was zero*) or equal to zero (*in the case at least one of the terms was zero*), and since $\text{sgn}(\sigma)$ is always equal to $\pm 1$, the summation is adding a bunch of terms with each of which equal to a multiple of $a^n$.

Since adding multiples of $a^n$ to other multiples of $a^n$ results in multiples of $a^n$, we have the overall sum is a multiple of $a^n$.

(*note: this is the more common* **definition** *for determinants of matrices and coincides with the definition of determinants for other operators which might not necessarily be expressible as matrices as opposed to using [Laplace Expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion)*)

Answer (score 2):

Let's do it by induction on $n$. Suppose that it holds for $n$ and let's show it for $n+1$. Expanding through any row or column, we get a sum of the form $\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\lambda_i \det B_i$, where $\lambda_i \in \{0,\pm a\}$ and $B_i$ is $n\times n$ and composed of $0$'s and $\pm a$'s. It follows that $\det A$ is divisible by $a^{n+1}$.