# Prove that an $n×n$ matrix with entries $+1$ or $-1$ has determinant divisible by $2^{n-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

> Prove that an $n×n$ matrix with entries $+1$ or $-1$ has determinant divisible by $2^{n-1}$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I don't know how to proceed.If the matrix has rank less than n then it's trivial.But what if the matrix is invertible.If We try to inspect the elements of the column so the total choice should be 2^n!!Then!!

Comment: @DominikKutek I have answered your question.Thank You.

Comment: add $1^{st}$ column to $2^{nd}$, $3^{th}$ ... columns, what can you say about the new columns?

Comment: Possibly duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2101303/601852

Comment: This is true for matrices all of whose entries are odd.

Comment: but the problem clearly says it is true for all matrices.And @Dominik Kutek I am not sure I understood the answers in the question referred by you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the first row, and either add or subtract it to each of rows $2$ through $n$ in order to cancel out the first entry in each of those rows to $0$. Doing this does not change the determinant of the matrix. When you have finished, you will have a matrix such that all entries except for the first row are even.

Now if you do cofactor expansion along the first column, you will see that the determinant of the whole matrix is equal to the determinant of the lower right$(n-1)\times (n-1)$ submatrix. Now divide the rows of this submatrix by $2$, one at a time, to see that each time the determinant is divided by $2$ as well. At the end you will be left with an integer matrix, which must therefore have integer determinant, and you will have done a total of $n-1$ divisions, proving that the original determinant was in fact a multiple of $2^{n-1}$.

Comment: Thanks!!!I am grateful.